# SQL : How to return result using Sub query using exists here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to select records from subquery using EXISTS

```
select * from dbo.EMP
where exists (
select a.* from  dbo.HREMP a
inner join dbo.emp  b
on a.ID=b.ID
inner join dbo.LOGO c
on b.id=c.EMPID
inner join dbo.LOGOACC d
on c.BADGENO=d.BADGENO
where d.ACCLVID in (2191,2292,2293,2294,2295,2296,2297))
```

> The above query list all the employee of the EMP table.?

My requirement is list only the employees present in EMP table who is present in my subquery.

Comment: Correlation on the outer table

Comment: how to solve it here  @shawnt00

Comment: Google "how to correlate exists query in sql". Read first search result.

Comment: please read my reply to "brien" @shawnt00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXISTS`

> Specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows.

In your case the `dbo.emp` already on outer `FROM` so you just need to connection outer `dbo.emp` id with `dbo.hremp` id which in `EXISTS`.

You can try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   dbo.emp AS m
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   dbo.hremp a 
                      INNER JOIN dbo.logo c 
                              ON b.id = c.empid 
                      INNER JOIN dbo.logoacc d 
                              ON c.badgeno = d.badgeno 
               WHERE  d.acclvid IN ( 2191, 2292, 2293, 2294, 
                                     2295, 2296, 2297 ) AND m.id = a.id)
```

But I think you can use this directly to get your expect.

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM   dbo.hremp a 
      INNER JOIN dbo.emp b 
              ON a.id = b.id 
      INNER JOIN dbo.logo c 
              ON b.id = c.empid 
      INNER JOIN dbo.logoacc d 
              ON c.badgeno = d.badgeno 
WHERE  d.acclvid IN ( 2191, 2292, 2293, 2294,2295, 2296, 2297)
```

**EDIT**

You can try this Query.

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM   dbo.hremp a 
      INNER JOIN dbo.emp b 
              ON a.id = b.id 
      INNER JOIN dbo.logo c 
              ON b.id = c.empid 
      INNER JOIN dbo.logoacc d 
              ON c.badgeno = d.badgeno 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM dbo.logoacc m
    WHERE 
        m.acclvid IN ( 2191, 2292, 2293, 2294,2295, 2296, 2297)
    AND 
        m.badgeno = d.badgeno 
)
```

[EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql)

Comment: the second one is working and it's correctly returning 653 rows ..good

Comment: The first one is only returning 507 rows and  i wonder how to do it using exists

Comment: still  the only 507 records returning, ie, in my HREMP table there is duplicate or multiple records for a single  ID.

Comment: how `ON b.id = c.empid  ` , ie , **b** is not defined in subquery

Comment: @coffemug Could you provide some sample data? or Did you try my new edit answer?

Comment: only 515 records returning,  it should return 653

Comment: same result, 507 records

Comment: @coffemug I modify my answer. :)

Comment: its returning  no result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468098/sqllisting-duplicate-records-from-multiple-join-statements

Comment: i put a follow up question. hope you will  look into it

Answer (score 1):

You need a correlation in `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.emp o
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   dbo.hremp a
                      inner join dbo.emp b
                              ON a.id = b.id
                      inner join dbo.logo c
                              ON b.id = c.empid
                      inner join dbo.logoacc d
                              ON c.badgeno = d.badgeno
               WHERE  d.acclvid IN ( 2191, 2292, 2293, 2294,
                                     2295, 2296, 2297 )
                      AND a.id = o.id)  -- correlation between subquery and outer.
```

I think this relation should also hold good for you?

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.emp b
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   dbo.hremp a
                      inner join dbo.logo c
                              ON a.id = c.empid
                      inner join dbo.logoacc d
                              ON c.badgeno = d.badgeno
               WHERE  d.acclvid IN ( 2191, 2292, 2293, 2294,
                                     2295, 2296, 2297 )
                      AND a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: But both queries were returning only 507 records , actually it needs to return 653 records .. hmm

Answer (score 0):

you have not connected the main with the subquerye.

```
select e.* 
from dbo.EMP e
where exists ( select 1 
                 from dbo.HREMP a 
                 join dbo.LOGO c
                   on c.EMPID = e.id 
                 join dbo.LOGOACC d
                   on d.BADGENO = c.BADGENO  
                  and d.ACCLVID in (2191,2292,2293,2294,2295,2296,2297)
                where a.ID = e.ID
             )
```

I will bet this does what you are looking for

```
select distinct e.* 
from dbo.EMP e
join dbo.HREMP a 
  on a.ID    = e.ID
join dbo.LOGO c
  on c.EMPID = e.id 
join dbo.LOGOACC d
  on d.BADGENO = c.BADGENO  
 and d.ACCLVID in (2191, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297)
```

Comment: if you avoid the distinct in the second query  its  returning  correct result. ie total 653 records .

Comment: first one is only returing 507 records and no records which is duplicate is not showing in the result

Comment: Correct is a matter of perspective.  The first is closest to the question you stated.

Comment: why the two queries returning different result . Your second query is correct but when we tries it with EXISTS its not giving the desired output

Comment: Desired and correct are not the same.  Again the first does what you asked for and evidently the second does what you meant to ask for.

Comment: there are duplicate records in my HREMP table, using exists its filtering and only returning one record ..

Comment: Now is it possible to retrieve only  the duplicate records  using the second query

Comment: Is it possible for you to submit a new question and clearly describe what you need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468098/sqllisting-duplicate-records-from-multiple-join-statements

Comment: This is the follow up question