# SQL:listing duplicate records from multiple join statements ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates

Helllo 
The below query  is returning all the employees after joining multiple tables

```
   select e.* 
    from dbo.EMP e
    join dbo.HREMP a 
      on a.ID    = e.ID
    join dbo.LOGO c
      on c.EMPID = e.id 
    join dbo.LOGOACC d
      on d.BADGENO = c.BADGENO  
     and d.ACCLVID in (2191, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297)
```

**Total 653 Records were returning**

> Now after executing the below query

```
with EmployeeCTE as
(
   select e.* 
        from dbo.EMP e
        join dbo.HREMP a 
          on a.ID    = e.ID
        join dbo.LOGO c
          on c.EMPID = e.id 
        join dbo.LOGOACC d
          on d.BADGENO = c.BADGENO  
         and d.ACCLVID in (2191, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297)
)
select k.id  from EmployeeCTE k
group  by ID
having count (k.id) >1
```

**I found that there are 135 records having count more than 1 .**

How to list all the records which is having more than one count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from (select e.*  
           , count(*) over (partition by e.id) as cnt
        from dbo.EMP e
        join dbo.HREMP a 
          on a.ID    = e.ID
        join dbo.LOGO c
          on c.EMPID = e.id 
        join dbo.LOGOACC d
          on d.BADGENO = c.BADGENO  
         and d.ACCLVID in (2191, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297) 
     ) tt 
where tt.cnt > 1
```